# Integrating drupal blog into static website

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, blogs

I have a static site with about 5-6 pages. I need to integrate a blog into this, build using Drupal.

What will be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

The question asked doesn't provide many specifics about the blog required, so rather than provide detailed technical steps on how to built it, this response is how I approached a very similar brief from a client a few months ago.

Drupal.org provides a pretty good starting point for how to approach building a blog in Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/blog. This page links to a recipe for a single user blog that may well give you the answer you're looking for: https://www.drupal.org/node/41373. Drupal core includes a Blog module, but this is intended for multi-user blogs.

There are a number of questions you should ask yourself about the blog you wish to build:

- Is it a single person blog or a multiple person (user) blog?
- What pages do you wish to feature, other than the main blogroll?

  - Posts by category
  - Posts by author
  - Posts by tags
  - Posts by month (archive display)
- What blocks (or widgets if you're coming from the WordPress world) do you want to include? These could include:

  - Recent posts
  - Archives
  - Category listings
  - User listings
  - Tag cloud
- Do you want to allow comments? If so, what spam settings do you want to have enabled? Do users need to be registered to comment?

All of this is possible in Drupal, but can take a while to configure as it doesn't come "out of box" as it does with WordPress or another package intended for blogging. All of the pages and blocks listed above are possible using Views, and the Comment module (included as part of Drupal Core) will take care of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do it opposite way - to setup common Drupal site and blog pages and then to integrate static pages into it. You can even benefit from Drupal and make static pages back-end editable with some wysiwyg editor.